# angular click on download link causing navigation to home page

Tags: angular

In angular 6, On downloadFile method, I am downloading the excel sheet from the WbeAPI. It all works fine. It's open up the dialog to save the file on drive but It navigate me to home page. So, I am on http://localhost:port/viewdetails where I have this button and as soon as i click on the fileName to download it navigate page back to my home page- which is dashboard. Below are the routes defined and I am not able to log the URL object which is being getting created in method. The entire code for the details is here:
[angular 6 download excel from API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55620049/angular-6-download-excel-from-api/55623352?noredirect=1#comment97962391_55623352)

```
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
    {
    path: 'admin/XXXXXX',
    component: XXXXXXComponent
    } ,
    {
      path: 'admin/YYYYYY',
      component: YYYYYYComponent
      } 
];
```

Comment: have you tried to add pathMatch: 'full' to your first route

Comment: {
    path: '',
    component: DashboardComponent, pathMatch: 'full'
  },

Comment: Just now i realize that navigation is caused by this href blank here ````  <ul>
            <li  *ngFor="let result of fetchedUploaded" (click)="downloadFile(result.fileName)" >
              <a href=''>{{ result.fileName }}</a>
            </li>
          </ul> ```` what should I set here???? because if i remove the href attribute then the fileName is not clickable

Comment: I tried to change href to  `      <a [href]="downloadURL" target="_self">{{ result.fileName }}</a> and 
downloadFile(fileName: string) {
  this.downloadURL = window.location.href;
  this.service.postAndGetResponse(fileName).subscribe(fileData => {...    `. this caused it to stay on same page but there is flicker like in asp.net pages have

Comment: I finally replaced the <a> with below   <button class="btn btn-link" style="padding :0px" role="link" type="button" name="op" value="result.fileName">{{ result.fileName }}</button> and all worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I finally replaced the  with below

```
    <button class="btn btn-link" style="padding :0px" role="link" type="button" name="op" 
 value="result.fileName">{{ result.fileName }}</button> 
and all worked fine
```